# Problems with testing Bootstrap modal windows with Codeception

Tags: testing, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeception

I'm having a little trouble testing the appearance of modal windows with a website I'm helping to build.  These modal windows are used to fill out forms and I'm writing tests to test if they appear and later to fill them in and test the submit functionality.

I'm using Codeception with the WebDriver module to test and frequently there are errors when trying to waitForElement with the modal.  It doesn't always result in an error though, sometimes Codeception seems to see the modal and other times it doesn't.

I'm wondering if there is a better automated testing framework for testing Twitter Bootstrap modal windows or if I'm just not doing something right.

Comment: Please post some code if you want people to check whether you're "not doing something right".

Comment: Does the modal window appear in an iFrame? If so you might want to look at `$I->switchToIFrame("name_of_iframe");`